# Limit by percent instead of number of rows without subqueries

Tags: postgresql

I would like to select the top 1% of rows; however, I cannot use subqueries to do it. I.e., this won't work:

```
SELECT * FROM mytbl
WHERE var='value'
ORDER BY id,random()
LIMIT(SELECT (COUNT(*) * 0.01)::integer FROM mytbl)
```

How would I accomplish the same output without using a subquery with limit?

Comment: `ORDER BY id, random()` does not make sense for me because ID should be unique. So random does not come to play

Comment: There are multiple rows with the same id. Think a "within-subjects" type of experimental design. Ultimately what I want is all of the rows for a random 1% sample of unique ids. So this will first sort the ids, and then sort those ids once grouped up in random order. Then I'll just grab the top 1% of rows and drop the rows for the last id since it's not likely complete.

Comment: The `tablesample` option can be used for that

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize [`PERCENT_RANK`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
WITH cte(ID, var, pc) AS
(
  SELECT ID, var, PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY random()) AS pc
  FROM mytbl
  WHERE var = 'value'
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE pc <= 0.01
ORDER BY id;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1ede2/3/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Just to be sure, I'm new to sql and I'm not clear how the order by is working here, all of the rows for a given id will appear sequentially in the table, and those groups of sequential ids will be sorted in random order?

Comment: @ChristieHaskell I just ordered your set by random, but if you have multiple id use:`PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id,random()) AS pc`

Comment: It executes, but the resulting table isn't correct. It returns a single row with a column for id, var and pc, whereas I'd like 1% of rows from the original table with all of the original columns, but don't want a fully random sample of rows. I need a random sample of distinct ids with all of the rows for each of those ids.

Comment: Sorry, by new I mean incredibly new and I couldn't figure out how to create fake data on that site (I've only used existing tables, I've never created them). I would still be interested in a purely sql solution as opposed to my python one if you have one.

Comment: @ChristieHaskell You can use data you have in real example(just make representional sample) that will recreate the case and make sure that you change all sensitive data with meaningless numbers/text like 'aaa','bbb','ccc',' 111,222,333.... Then just paste in sqlfiddle.com INSERT INTO values for one table.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have your data, of course, but I have no trouble using a sub query in the `LIMIT` clause.

However, the sub query contains only the `count(*)` part and I then multiply the result by `0.01`:

```
SELECT * FROM mytbl
WHERE var='value'
ORDER BY id,random()
LIMIT(SELECT count(*) FROM mytbl)*0.01;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with Python using the `psycopg2` package:

```
    cur.execute("SELECT ROUND(COUNT(id)*0.01,0)
                 FROM mytbl")
    nrows = str([int(d[0]) for d in cur.fetchall()][0])
    cur.execute("SELECT * 
                 FROM mytbl
                 WHERE var='value'
                 ORDER BY id, random() LIMIT (%s)",nrows)
```

Perhaps there is a more elegant solution using just SQL, or a more efficient one, but this does exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you sure? You always get the same ids due to `order by id`. It is hardly a a random sample.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you need:

1. Random 1% sample of all rows,
2. If some `id` is within the sample, all rows with the same `id` must be there too.

The follow sql should do the trick:

```
with ids as (
    select   id,
             total,
             sum(cnt) over (order by max(rnd)) running_total
    from     (
               select id,
                      count(*) over (partition by id) cnt,
                      count(*) over () total,
                      row_number() over(order by random()) rnd
               from   mytbl
             ) q
    group by id,
             cnt,
             total
)
select   mytbl.*
from     mytbl,
         ids
where    mytbl.id = ids.id
and      ids.running_total <= ids.total * 0.01
order by mytbl.id;
```